# JavaScript charts - dynamically adding data points

Tags: javascript, ajax, canvas, charts, jqplot

I am trying to dynamically add data points to jqplot as a result of AJAX received data, but I do not see a way to accomplish this. Is this not possible?

If it isn't, what other packages are available that can accomplish the same basic graphing plus allow for dynamic data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to check the example below on how this is handled in [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/). Flot is an open-source plotting library based on [jQuery](http://jquery.com), like [jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com/). Both libraries are very similar.

This is how fetching and plotting the data with AJAX would look like in code:

```
function fetchData() {
   $.ajax({
      url:      "json_fetch_new_data.php",
      method:   "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      success:  function(series) {
         var data = [ series ];

         $.plot($("#placeholder"), data, options);
      }
   });

   setTimeout(fetchData, 1000);
}
```

Make sure to check the following demo to see it in action:

- [Flot Examples - Updating graphs with AJAX](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/ajax.html)

For further information on Flot:

- [Flot Project Site](http://code.google.com/p/flot/)
- [Flot Examples](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/)
- [Other Flot Examples](http://www.midnightkite.com/flot/examples/)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. I'm switching to Flot.